# пишу mvс фреймворк

Tags: php

Есть пустуа бд в *phpMyAdmin* на *OpenServer*. Вход у меня без пароля. Ввел все данные, но у меня вылетает ошибка.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'bd_frame'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in W:\domains\mvcframe\application\lib\Db.php:14 Stack trace: #0 W:\domains\mvcframe\application\lib\Db.php(14): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'bd_frame', '') #1 
W:\domains\mvcframe\application\controllers\MainController.php(12): application\lib\Db->__construct() #2 
W:\domains\mvcframe\application\core\Router.php(42): application\controllers\MainController->indexAction() #3 
W:\domains\mvcframe\index.php(17): application\core\Router->run() #4 {main} thrown in W:\domains\mvcframe\application\lib\Db.php on line 14
```

Код

```
<?php

return [
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'name' => 'bd_frame',
    'user' => 'bd_frame',
    'password' => '',
];  

?>


<?php 

namespace application\lib;

use PDO;

class Db {

    protected $db;

    public function __construct() {
        $config = require 'application/config/db.php';
        $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$config['host'].';dbname='.$config['name'].'', $config['user'], 
            $config['password']);
    }

    public function query($sql) {

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: а если вместо ` $config['password']` просто вписать пустоту, тогда подключается?

Comment: а `'user' => 'root'` пробовали?